# npm can't find package.json when running docker container with compose

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I am trying to wire up my Angular 7 client app into docker compose locally.

I get the following error when I docker-compose up:

```
client-app    | npm ERR! errno -2
client-app    | npm ERR! syscall open
client-app    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9.6.1

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4200

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY . /app

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm rebuild node-sass

CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-start"]
```

The compose part for the client is:

```
  client-app:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}client
    container_name: client-app
    ports:
      - "4200:81"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ClientApp/Dockerfile
```

package.json is in the ClientApp folder along-side Dockerfile, I would assume COPY . /app should copy the package.json to the container. I don't have any excludes in dockerignore. I am using Docker for Windows with Unix containers. I tried npm init before (but that will create an empty package.json anyway) and looked through the SO posts but most of the dockerfile definitions look exactly the same. I also tried: COPY package*.json ./ additionally and building the image with --no-cache.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your *Dockerfile* is fine, and `COPY package*.json ./` is not necessary - its being copied with your entire app.

The problem is in your *docker-compose* file.

you defined:

```
build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ClientApp/Dockerfile
```

that means, your *Dockerfile* will accept the docker-compose context, which is 1 directory above:

```
├── docker-compose.yml -- this is the actual context
└── ClientApp
    ├── Dockerfile -- this is the expected context
```

so when the CMD is running, it is 1 directory above the *package.json*, therefore it cannot run the command and the container exits.

to fix it, give your *docker-compose* file the correct context:

```
build:
      context: ClientApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Efrat @Kirill Ermolov, this solved the issue, I prefer the approach with docker compose since I want to sometimes run the client separately for CI unit tests and leaving it with one working dockerfile seems a better option.

Answer (score 3):

This command `COPY package*.json ./` will try copy `package.json` from root dir. However looks like you need to copy `package.json` from `ClientApp` dir

Two way to fix this:
1) Change compose file `context: ./ClientApp/`
2) Change docker file `COPY ./ClientApp/package.json /app/package.json`

I think better to change docker file because in feature you may want to copy some file from root dir