# Can't run vue using docker-compose - can't find package.json

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm

I'm not able to run my Vue app using Docker and docker-compose. All the other apps and services are running (a few .NET apps, nginx-proxy and letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) but when running the vue app I get the following err:

```
| npm ERR! path /app/package.json
| npm ERR! code ENOENT
| npm ERR! errno -2
| npm ERR! syscall open
| npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
| npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

This is how my docker-compose.yaml looks like:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/certs/_data:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/vhost/_data:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/html/_data:/usr/share/nginx/html
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/config/_data:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx/_data:/etc/init.d/
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
      - vue-app
  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
    environment:
        - DEFAULT_EMAIL=mail@mail.com
        - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/certs/_data:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/vhost/_data:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/html/_data:/usr/share/nginx/html
  app1:
    image: user/app1:latest
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com,www.example.com
        - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.com,www.example.com
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/sqllite/_data:/app/data
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/uploadfolder/_data:/app/wwwroot/uploads
  app2:
    build: ~/app_2
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=app2.example.com,www.app2.example.com
        - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=app2.example.com,www.app2.example.com
  vue-app:
    build: ~/vue_app
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=vueapp.example.com,www.vueapp.example.com
        - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=vueapp.example.com,www.vueapp.example.com
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - /app/node_modules
volumes:
  certs:
  vhost:
  html:   
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

And my Docker file for the vue-app:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @vue/cli@3.7.0 -g

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

The file structure on my server is:

```
root   
| docker-compose.yaml
|
|__app_2
|  Dockerfile (in the project root)
|
|__vue_app
   Dockerfile (in the project root)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look into this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589014/npm-cant-find-package-json-when-running-docker-container-with-compose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, you have this line :

```
vue-app:
    ...
    volumes:
        - .:/app
```

Here you are just overriding all the content of your `/app` directory inside your container (the one containing the `package.json` file) with the content of your current directory.
That's why you have the error telling you that the file does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.
I followed this tutorial which is using those volumes in the docker-compose:
https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-vue-app/